# Find most common element from json

Tags: php, twig

In my Twig file I am looping trough an array from a JSON file. For example

```
r.dep[1].iata_code: "FRA"
r.dep[2].iata_code: "AMS"
r.dep[3].iata_code: "AMS"
r.dep[3].iata_code: "DBM"
```

How can I find the most common value (in this case AMS) and set this in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parse the incoming json. Than build a new array and sort that array.

Try this:

```
$r = json_decode($jsonstring); // parse your json string

$items = []; // define empty array

// Loop through the parsed JSON, counting occurrences
foreach($r->dep as $dep) {
   if (array_key_exists($dep->iata_code, $items) {
      $items[$dep->iata_code]++;
   } else {
      $items[$dep->iata_code] = 1;
   }
}

// Now reverse sort the array
arsort($items);

// Max item is now the first one:
$max = array_keys($items)[0]; // AMS
```